# Google Cloud DLP tokenization of tabular data with CryptoDeterministicConfig and custom infotype

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, regex-greedy, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to tokenize the string value (passed in the tabular format) with custom regex infotype, but having issues when I add more than one row in the table. If I pass the single row, it successfully tokenize the string_value and returns the encoded string. I'm using the python library for this.

Custom info type is currently set to any value in a string for demo purpose and wrapped key is present in cloud KMS (removed it here for security reasons).

Following is the configuration that I am using:

```
# Construct FPE configuration dictionary
crypto_replace_ffx_fpe_config = {
    "crypto_key": {
        "kms_wrapped": {
            "wrapped_key": wrapped_key,
            "crypto_key_name": key_name,
        }
    }
}
# Add surrogate type
if surrogate_type:
    crypto_replace_ffx_fpe_config["surrogate_info_type"] = {
        "name": surrogate_type
    }

# Construct inspect configuration dictionary
inspect_config = {
    #"info_types": [{"name": info_type} for info_type in info_types],
    #"min_likelihood": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
    "custom_info_types": [
        {
            "info_type": {
                "name": "custom"
            },
            "exclusion_type": "EXCLUSION_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
            "likelihood": "POSSIBLE",
            "regex": {
                "pattern": "(?:.*)"
                #"pattern": ".*"
            }
        }
    ]
}

# Construct deidentify configuration dictionary
deidentify_config = {
    "info_type_transformations": {
        "transformations": [
            {
                "primitive_transformation": {
                    "crypto_deterministic_config": crypto_replace_ffx_fpe_config
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
item={
    "table":{
        "headers":[{
            "name":header
            } for header in data_headers
        ],
        "rows":[
            {
                "values":[
                    {
                        "string_value":"asa s.com"
                    }
                ]
            },  #Issue starts when the below row is added having any value in string_value
            {
                "values":
                [
                    {
                        "string_value":"14562@gmail.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

    # Call the API
response = dlp.deidentify_content(
    parent,
    inspect_config=inspect_config,
    deidentify_config=deidentify_config,
    item=item,
)

# Print results
return response.item.table
```

If i am sending one row of data, getting response  as

```
headers {
  name: "token"
}
rows {
  values {
    string_value: "EMAIL_ADDRESS(XX):XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="
  }
}
```

And when i am sending item with more than one row, i am getting what i originally sent to api as it is back:
For example:

```
headers {
    name: "token"
}
rows {
      values {
        string_value: "asa s.com"
    }
}
rows {
    values {
        string_value: "14562@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you are using InfoTypeTransformations  for DeidentifyConfig. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#de-identification_transformations), you may need to use RecordTransformations instead, as this category of transformation "is applied to values within submitted tabular text data that are identified as a specific infoType, or on an entire column of tabular data". You can learn more about RecordTransformations [here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#record_transformations).
Let me know what you think of it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using [InfoTypeTransformations](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#infotype_transformations) for [DeidentifyConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/organizations.deidentifyTemplates#deidentifyconfig).

As per the documentation, you should use [RecordTransformations](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#record_transformations) instead, as this category of transformation "is applied to values within submitted tabular text data that are identified as a specific infoType, or on an entire column of tabular data" and treat the dataset as structured.